# Rails: Problems with index view on nested resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have nested resources with 2 models - products and product_images. I'm using Carrierwave to upload the images.
My products model looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :allow_destroy => :true
end
```

My product_images model looks like this:

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
belongs_to :product
end
```

My products_controller looks like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

def index
@products = Product.all
end

def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@images = @product.product_images
end

def new
@product = Product.new
@product.product_images.build
end
...
```

This is all fine working in my Show view, also with the thumb versions.
However I can't manage to get the index view working. I'm trying to display the first image in the Product_images table but it won't work out.

Here's my index view:

```
<table>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">

<td class="list_description">
<dl>
<dt><%= product.title %></dt>
</dl>
</td>
<td>
<%= image_tag(product.product_image.first ) %>
</td>
</td>
...
</table>
```

My routes first looked like this:

```
resources :products
```

then I tried this:
    resources :products do
    resources :product_images
    end

How can I make the images be accessible in my index view? Could anybody help me please to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `image_tag` line is wrong. It should be

```
image_tag product.product_images.first.image_url
```

It's right there in [the examples in Capybara's README](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location) :)

Comment: Sometimes it can be so simple! I tried for two days everything with my routes an models and controllers. It's still a long way to learn Rails!
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No worries. You can mark the question as answered, by the way :)